# Foot Image Segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am working on segmenting plantar foot image. i am finding it difficult to find the edges of the foot without the details inside. Please take a look at the canny edge detected. It is full of noise and I would require a binary image of the two foot as given in 2nd image. Please help.[image]

[image]

Comment: Convolutional neural networks are the hotness right now in imaging tasks. I'd start researching there.

Comment: What did you try allready? There is million thinks you can do. Check scikit image tutorial for examples

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I have started to work on matlab. CNNs I would like to explore.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can think of using Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) to solve such segmentation problem, e.g. [FCN](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf), pipeline of which is to classify each pixel of an image into target or background using a CNN classifier. Similarly, you can train such a CNN using images with foot region labeled as target and others as background.

An interesting research [deep mask](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask) may also shed some light on this problem.